# What's wrong with the parametrized method?

Tags: java

Here is the signature of my method running scheduled tasks:

```
private <E extends Enum<E>, T extends Task<E>> void runJob(T task, Map<Enum<E>, 
                                                           Job> taskTypeJobMap, 
                                                           Enum<E> taskType, 
                                                           JpaRepository<T, Long> repository)
```

Here is the method which runs the previous one:

```
private void runJob(TaskQueue task, Map<TaskType, Job> taskTypeJobMap) {
    runJob(task, taskTypeJobMap, null, taskQueueRepository);
}
```

Here you can see that my classes are parametrized: (TaskType is Enum)

```
public class TaskQueue implements Task<TaskType> { /* ... */ }
public interface Task <T extends Enum<T>> { /* ... */ }
public interface TaskQueueRepository extends JpaRepository<TaskQueue, Long> { /* ... */ }
```

But my IDE shows an exception:
[image]
Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing a `Map<Enum<E>,Job>`, you are passing a `Map<TaskType,Job>`. The reason is that generics in Java are not covariant, complicated by the fact that although `TaskType` is an `Enum<TaskType>`, and the only possible `Enum<TaskType>`, an `Enum<TaskType>` in the Java typesystem is **not** a `TaskType`.

You need to change the signature of your method to either use:

- `Map<TaskType,Job>` (accepts only maps with `TaskType` as key), or
- `Map<E,Job>`

Similarly, it would probably be better to change the type of the `taskType` parameter to `E` as well.